# Visual studio, Windows Phone emulator not working

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

Made an app in

- visual studio 2013
- downloaded windows phone 8.1, latest version

Tried running my app, and it just keeps giving me this error.

I've tried

- uninstalling,
- using repair,
- redownloading and reinstalling,
- restarting my computer,
- deleting a folder that a couple people recommended, but nothing.

  ```
  (Error  1   Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
  {2D0A16C9-53D9-42C1-BCC2-8D2A135E2163} failed due to the following 
  error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception
  from HRESULT: 0x8007007E). Please rebuild the solution and try again.
      0   0   )
  ```

anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Please also provide an example of your App code otherwise people can't reproduce that error.

Answer (score 0):

The CLSID you reference above is the VSD (Visual Studio Device) Connection Manager. Looks like VS can't find the VSD ConnectionManager.

A few things to look at:

1. Do you have Hyper-V enabled and running? If not, you need to be running Hyper-V in order to run the Windows Phone emulator.
2. In Hyper-V Manager, do you see the Windows Phone emulator images listed?
3. Using Hyper-V Manager, can you start any of the emulator images:
   [image]
4. In Visual Studio, do you see the emulators listed in the build & debug target toolbar:
   [image]

If any of the above steps fail, you should focus on resolving those steps in order before continuing.